# Initially assigned variables

Tags: c#, variables, variable-assignment

The following two categories of variables are initially assigned:

- Instance variables of class instances.
- Instance variables of initially assigned struct variables.

Now what does initially assigned struct variables mean?

We're not talking about local variable, right? So we're talking about field variables (in both of these categories) that are used in function member definitions?

Clarifying this would be really appreciated. And thanks in advance!

Comment: structs are not nullable, so they must have a value - int, bool, enums are also in that category.

Answer (score 8):

> The following two categories of variables are initially assigned: (1) Instance variables of class instances and (2) Instance variables of initially assigned struct variables.  What does "initially assigned struct variables" mean?

It means an *initially assigned variable of struct type*.

Follow along.

```
class C 
{
    public int i;
}
...
C c = new C();
Console.WriteLine(c.i);
```

`c.i` is an instance variable of a class, so it is *initially assigned*.

```
struct S 
{
    public int j;
}
class D 
{
    public S t;
}
...
D d = new D();
Console.WriteLine(d.t.j);
```

`d.t` is an instance variable of a class, so it is initially assigned. `d.t.j` is an instance variable of a struct `S`, and the variable `d.t` of type `S` is initially assigned, therefore `d.t.j` is also initially assigned.

That is, a field of a struct is initially assigned if the variable that holds the value of the struct is *itself* initially assigned.

By contrast:

```
void M()
{
    int q;
    Console.WriteLine(q); // Error
    S u;
    Console.WriteLine(u.j); // Error
```

Neither `q` nor `u` are initially assigned; they are not fields of any class. Since `u` is not initially assigned, `u.j` is not either.

Make sense now?

Comment: Makes perfect since! Greatly appreciated Eric! I asked my instructor this question two times and he never even got close to making sense.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear. But it is correct that a *field* (instance or static) of a class or struct is always considered assigned. It will have the default value of the type, which is `null` for reference types and nullable types, and "zero" or something similar to zero for other value types.

In contrast a *local variable*, that is a variable declared inside a method (or constructor, or accessor, etc.) must be explicitly assigned to before it is used.

In the example:

```
class Example
{
    int field;

    void Method()
    {
        int local;
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

the `field` is considered assigned automatically and will have the initial value `0`, whereas the variable `local` is unassigned and must be assigned to (later in the same method) before it can be used (even later in the same method).

An unassigned local variable may be passed as an `out` parameter of a method, though.

**EDIT:** (after helpful comments)

My answer above gives a pretty precise description for (static and non-static) fields of classes and for static fields of structs. But there was missing something, as the comments pointed out, in case of instance fields of structs.

A struct instance is fully assigned when all its instance fields are fully assigned. Given the following (mutable!!) struct:

```
struct SomeStruct
{
    public int AlphaField;
    public int BetaField;
}
```

then the following is legal:

```
void M()
{
    SomeStruct localSS;
    // localSS and its fields are not assigned, and can't be read yet

    localSS.AlphaField = 7;           // legal
    int useA = localSS.AlphaField;    // legal, AlphaField is assigned
    // localSS and its remaining field BetaField are not assigned

    localSS.BetaField = 13;
    string useB = localSS.ToString(); // legal, localSS variable is now fully assigned
}
```

Even if the above example seems crazy (because mutable structs are discouraged by most people), it is still entirely equivalent to what happens inside a user-defined instance constructor of a struct. The C# Specification uses this sentence: *The `this` variable of an instance constructor of a struct behaves exactly the same as an `out` parameter of the struct type—in particular, this means that the variable must be definitely assigned in every execution path of the instance constructor.*

Note that one way for an instance constructor of a struct to assign all fields, is to chain another instance constructor with the `: this(...)` constructor chaining syntax.

Also note that instance constructors of structs must take parameters. The expression `new SomeStruct()` (with empty parameter list) is equivalent to `default(SomeStruct)` and evaluates to the definitely assigned instance of `SomeStruct` where all fields have their default values.

Comment: But fields of structs are not initially assigned. Only fields of classes are.

Comment: But fields of structs are not initially assigned. Only fields of classes are.

Comment: @user2247389 Well, in a sense you're right. In the example `struct MyStruct { int field; }` we give no instnace constructors. But it is still allowed to say `var ms = new MyStruct();`. In that case the `field` on `ms` will have the value `0`. But if you do write an instance constructor for your struct, all instance fields will have to be assigend to before control leaves the constructor. And it is not allowed to _use_ the fields inside the instance constructor before they are assigned to. So my answer missed that detail. One way of assigning all fields, is to _chain_ another constructor.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen What about `S s; /* uninitialized struct local variable */ int x = s.F; /* error, field might not be initialized */ s.F = 42; int y = s.F; /* valid now */`?

Comment: @svick That's a great example. I'll see if I can update my answer.

Answer (score -1):

A class (in C#) is a definition of a reference type.  This means that any members of that class are stored as references.

A struct (in C#) is a definition of a value type.  Any members of this class are stored as values, not as references.

Reference types are able to be unassigned, because they don't need to be assigned until they're used.  Using an unassigned class instance member would result in a runtime error.

Value types need a value to store, because they would not be able to determine their memory space otherwise.  Using an unassigned struct member would result in a compile time error.

Comment: Are you saying that if I have a class that contains five `int`s as members, then each `int` is stored as a separate reference? Or that a struct with a `string` member won't store that `string` as a reference? That's certainly not right. Reference and value types are not about the storage of members of the type, but about instances of the type itself.

Comment: No, that's not what I'm saying at all.  I'm saying each instance of the class is stored as a reference.  `int` is a value type, and `string` is a reference type that is treated as a value type in most cases.  That's why you don't need to say `string s = new String("Hello")`.  But obviously the Eric Lippert answer is 9001x better, so please downvote away, rather than explaining what's wrong with the answer or editing it so it's "correct".

Comment: Maybe that's what you meant, but it's not what you're saying (at least not as I understand it). Your answer talks about members of a class, not its instances. (And I'm confused, I *did* explain what I think is wrong with your answer.)

Comment: The question is "what does *initially assigned struct variables* mean?" Did you answer that question?

Comment: @EricLippert I thought I did.  I'm not sure what's not clear about my answer.  I think there's value in multiple ways of explaining something, and I would like to make sure my verbal explanation is complete.  In this case, your code explanation is more complete, but I would rather fix my answer than delete it.  Being considered wrong/incomplete bothers me more than the loss of points a downvote conveys :)